# How do I configure eclipse to autocomplete Css classes/ids in html/php files?

Tags: css, eclipse, autocomplete

I am developing web applications using eclipse with php etc.

How can I tell eclipse to suggest stuff (autocomplete) while I do something like:

`<li class="` <-- here suggest available classes

`<li id="` <-- and here the available ids

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try the Aptana Studio eclipse plugin
http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html

Comment: Dont download the plugin it will change all your settings. Use standalone aptana studio.